# Error initialization of immutable values in functions (Swift)

Tags: swift, constants

I have a test function and I keep getting an error when I have a local constant; however, when the constant is global I don't get errors.

```
func main(tempf: Double){
     let tempf = 70
}
```

The output is

```
Temperature.swift:4:7: warning: initialization of immutable value 'tempf' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it
  let tempf = 70
  ~~~~^~~~~
  _
```

Comment: It's just a warning, not an error. You can ignore it.

Comment: I'm not sure what the intent is here -- main takes an argument of `tempf`, which doesn't get used and the name is immediately shadowed by writing `let tempf = ...`. And, you get the warning, because you don't *use* `tempf` at all. Obviously, there's more to this code, as it doesn't *do* anything right now, so it's hard to say what *should* be happening.